# Merging 2 records (variables) in Postgresql to return them

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(user_id bigint)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
  $$
    declare 
      rec1 RECORD;
      rec2 RECORD;
      result RECORD;

    begin
      select * into rec1 from table1 where ....
      select * into rec2 from table2 where ....

      return result;
    end; 
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How do I merge the results from `rec1` and `rec2` into `result` record? I want to group these records by a certain column (say, it's called `user_id`).

If I do this:

```
select rec1.*, rec2.* into result;
```

there are 2 errors: this is not grouped by `user_id` and at runtime it says `ERROR:  record type has not been registered`

**P.S.** Actually, grouping by is not important. I just want to return `rec1` and `rec2` together as a tuple. I don't know how either return them both separately (without out parameters) or how to merge them into one record and return it.

Comment: You say "I want to group these records by a certain column" then you say "grouping by is not important."  You should probably decide which it is since the answer will depend.

Answer (score 3):

Record has no substructure, and any attempt to access a field in it will draw a run-time error [Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS).

As i can see, your problem can be solved using [rowtype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES) variable, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(user_id bigint)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
declare 
result RECORD;
t1_row table1%ROWTYPE;      
t2_row table2%ROWTYPE;  

begin
select * into t1_row from table1; -- limit 1 ?
select * into t2_row from table2; -- limit 1; ?

select t1_row.*, t2_row.* into result;
return result;
end; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: what are rec1 and rec2 used for?

Comment: @Alex Oups, i forgot to remove them from your example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess about with PL/PgSQL for this. Use a subquery to fetch the whole-row variable for each table, then expand them in the outer query.

```
  select 
    (SELECT table1 FROM table1 where ....).*, 
    (SELECT table2 from table2 where ....).*;
```

... but I strongly suspect you really just want to *join* two tables on a common key and return the resulting tuple, in which case your procedure becomes a simple `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` for:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (user_id);
```

If you must do it in PL/PgSQL for some reason I suspect you'll need:

```
declare 
      rec1 table1%ROWTYPE;
      rec2 table2%ROWTYPE;
      result RECORD;
```

i.e. declare the records as of being the type of the table, so they're no longer anonymous records.  (The `%ROWTYPE` isn't strictly required, but it makes it clearer to people who don't know that every table in PostgreSQL is also a type).